# Exceptions Caught and Ignored in Legacy code

Tags: java, exception

There is a legacy Java project.

During the code review, I have noticed that my colleagues replaced the code

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ok = false;
    }
    // and ok was never used since then
```

with

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

That is, the worst practice "ignore the exception" was replaced by the second worst "print the exception to stdout and go on". (The colleagues believe that the code does not get worse because of that.)

I know that there is a whole [holy war](http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions) about it, and that really clever people advice everyone to first of all *think* before catching exceptions. Unfortunately, it looks like this already has not been done. The legacy code catches exceptions and ignores them. It is possible to modify the code to throw an exception instead of ignoring it, but nobody knows how many use case scenarios will break because of that. Unit tests do not help because the method is not covered by unit tests. Nobody even knows in how many scenarios the method gets called.

***Given that the contract between the caller and the called method is not clear, what can we do with legacy code that catches and ignores exceptions?***

Comment: You could add monitoring for log files to raise alerts if stack trace was printed to logs. At least it could help you to get some statistics on how often exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases where Exceptions are expected and it is safe to go on. In any case you should use a logger framework to log exceptions rather than

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

So first you should transform this into

```
logger.error("context", e);
```

Some options:

- Use logs to detect which Exceptions are okay, and demote them to `logger.info()` or `logger.debug()` (as commented by @Ivan)
- after some time, change the remaining locations to throw a new **checked** exception. This will allow you to get compiler feedback about which other code will be impacted. Later you can revert to unchecked.

  - start unit testing
  - start protecting the main loop / entry points of your product from unchecked exceptions happening anywhere